# Database modeling

Tags: mysql, database, modeling

My question is about modeling a particular situation:
In my model I have tables: User, Offices and Partners.
The system has different user profiles: users of Office (counselors, principals, assistants), users for Partners (Institutions,..), admin users.
What is the best way to model the relationship between office users and partner users if:
- The users are unique (two users should have the same login - should be in only 1 table)
- An office user is associated to only one office
- A partner user is associated only with a partner.

It should be a table for office users and one for partners users?
A many to many relationships in this case would not work, right?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are [a bunch of example models](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/) listed here. Reading through some of them might provide some inspiration.

Comment: @Seth. Those are not "models", they have nothing to do with databases, they are buckets of fish. Juan has asked a straight technical question, and SO provides technical answers (at least some of us do) ... not inspiration.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA - They are diagrams of relational data structures. As such, they have everything to do with databases, but very little to do with fish. I realize that I didn't provide an answer, which is why I posted it as a comment.

Comment: @Seth. Really ? Please identify specifically, anything that is "relational" or "database" about them.  To me they look like fish.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided enough definition re Partners and Offices, so those parts of the model are not yet complete, but I think the main question you are asking is answered in this [**▶Data Model◀**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/juanalsa%20DM.pdf). As I understand it:

- User (login, UserName is unique, and you do not want that  to be unclear)
- Users are exclusively (that is the X in the half-circle) Office/Partner/Administrator

  - that requires a Supertype-Subtype structure.  The cardinality is 1::0-1
- Users belong to (?) an Office or a Partner, exclusively.

  - That may be OfficeType or OfficeTitle.

If you define that last item a bit more, I can finish the model.

Readers who are unfamiliar with the Standard for Modelling Relational Databases may find the [**▶IDEF1X Notation◀**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) helpful.

Comment: can I ask you the name of the software you use to draw your data models? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this model will never change I would add a field to the users to determine where they belong. You could put an enum named user_type with possible values of 'office', 'partner', or 'admin'.. And then you could put in columns of office_id, and partner_id so you could join the tables as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best route would be to go with an account group structure, where you use an association table to determine who's in what group...

**group**

id | name

**group_assoc**

group_id | account_id